# Get IMask Value

Tags: javascript, imaskjs

I would like to retrieve the 'value' from the below using JavaScript:

InputMask {el: HTMLMaskElement, masked: MaskedPattern, _listeners: {…}, _value: '', _unmaskedValue: '', …}
alignCursor: ƒ ()
alignCursorFriendly: ƒ ()
el: HTMLMaskElement {input: input#l3-19_0-Input_Value.form-control.input_js.OSFillParent, _handlers: {…}}
masked: MaskedPattern {*value: '', lazy: true, placeholderChar: '*', mask: 'aaaa0000000', definitions: {…}, …}
_changingCursorPos: 11
_listeners: {}
_onChange: ƒ ()
_onDrop: ƒ ()
_onInput: ƒ ()
_saveSelection: ƒ ()
_selection: {start: 11, end: 11}
_unmaskedValue: "aaaa1234567"
_value: "aaaa1234567"
cursorPos: (...)
mask: (...)
selectionStart: (...)
typedValue: (...)
unmaskedValue: (...)
value: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object

This is the logged value of:

var mask = new IMask(element, maskOptions);

I have tried:

console.log(mask.value) and console.log(mask.unmaskedValue) but neither has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mask.unmaskedValue`

```
var masked = IMask(element, {
  mask: /^\d+$/
});

console.log(masked.typedValue);
```